# How can I load a password-protected private key from a .pem file with M2Crypto?

Tags: python, m2crypto, pem, python-2.4

I have a password-protected private key in a .pem file; I want to use it to sign requests to a remote server. I'm able to load the key and enter the passphrase after being prompted for it:

```
python
>>> import M2Crypto
>>> pk = M2Crypto.RSA.load_key('private.pem')
Enter passphrase:
>>>
```

However, I need this for a server process which is restarted every morning, and thus the passphrase must be passed automatically somehow.  The load_key method supports a callback argument for this purpose, so I tried several variants of:

```
>>> def gimmepw():
...     return 'mysecret'
...
>>> pk = M2Crypto.RSA.load_key('private.pem', gimmepw)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in ?
  File "/usr/local/Plone/Python-2.4/.../M2Crypto/RSA.py", line 351, in load_key
    return load_key_bio(bio, callback)
  File "/usr/local/Plone/Python-2.4/.../M2Crypto/RSA.py", line 372, in load_key_bio
    rsa_error()
  File "/usr/local/Plone/Python-2.4/.../M2Crypto/RSA.py", line 302, in rsa_error
    raise RSAError, m2.err_reason_error_string(m2.err_get_error())
M2Crypto.RSA.RSAError: bad password read
>>>
```

*(replace "..." by "lib/python2.4/site-packages")*

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is due to the lack of parameter support in your callback function. As it will be called with at least one parameter, a `TypeError` exception will occurred (which is catched by M2Crypto).

```
>>> def gimmepw(*args):
...     print 'args:', repr(args)
...     return 'test'
... 
>>> M2Crypto.RSA.load_key('key.pem', gimmepw)
args: (0,)
<M2Crypto.RSA.RSA instance at 0xb6e8050c>
```

You should try:

```
def gimmepw(*args):
    return 'mysecret'
```

Answer (score 1):

One caveat: As of Python 2.7, the return value of your `callback` method must return a `str` type.

For example, a `unicode` type will error out in the same way.

```
>>> def gimmepw(*args):
...     return u'test'
... 
>>> M2Crypto.RSA.load_key('key.pem', gimmepw)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test_intuit_data.py", line 76, in <module>
    intuit_rsa_key = RSA.load_key(file='key.pem', callback=gimmepw)
  File "lib/python2.7/site-packages/M2Crypto/RSA.py", line 351, in load_key
    return load_key_bio(bio, callback)
  File "lib/python2.7/site-packages/M2Crypto/RSA.py", line 372, in load_key_bio
    rsa_error()
  File "lib/python2.7/site-packages/M2Crypto/RSA.py", line 302, in rsa_error
    raise RSAError, m2.err_reason_error_string(m2.err_get_error())
M2Crypto.RSA.RSAError: bad password read
```

If you are using any input other than a `str` type, be sure to cast to a `str` appropriately:

```
>>> def gimmepw(*args):
...     return str(u'test')
... 
>>> M2Crypto.RSA.load_key('key.pem', gimmepw)
<M2Crypto.RSA.RSA instance at 0xb6e8050c>
```